Pylance invalid character \u0
I've been trying to use both echo and Write-Output comands in Powershell terminal and both are returning this invalid character error.
And yeah, my vscode is set to UTF-8.

I tried looking up for it or even mess around in some Pylance configs, and nothing helps. Fun fact is, echo works perfectly when I try it on CMD.

> (Out-File cmdlet) default encoding in pwsh 5.1 is unicode and pwsh 7 utf8 is without a BOM. try using 'hey' | Set-Content oi.py -Encoding utf8 instead.

The linked duplicate's question is more abstract than this one, but the accepted answer there hopefully answers this one too.
